# How do I display items in adapter when fragment is returned to the layout via the back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a flow of fragments that my users can cycle through. To best understand its architecture, think of an install wizard. I have one parent activity that contains a FrameLayout in its ViewGroup and a user can navigate forward or backwards through the wizard. A user starts at fragment1 and ends at fragmentN such that navigating forward, the fragment manager would have a set like [Fragment1, Fragment2]. My issue is that Fragment1 is a fragment that hosts a nested fragment. This nested fragment is a RecyclerView implementation. When a user navigates back to Fragment1 from Fragment2 (popping the back stack) Fragment1 recreates its view as it should given its lifecycle, I do not set layout managers or adapters on the recycler view again because the view remembers the ones that it had however, despite my adapter being retained and containing data, none of it displays in the view.

To give a rough code impression / pseudo code:

- Begin Wizard;
- FragmentManger.getChildren() -> returns Fragment1
- Fragment1 is a fragment that contains a nested fragment whose job is to act like a RecyclerView feed

The nested feeds code for `onViewCreated()` looks like this (java):

```
if (rvActions == null) {
    // Grab a reference to the recycler widget
    rvActions = view.findViewById(R.id.feed_recycler);
    rvActions.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // grab the appropriate layout manager from the injected factory then attach it to the recycler
    if (layoutManager == null) {
        layoutManager = feedFactory.getLayoutManager();
        rvActions.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    // Grab the appropriate adapter from the injected factory then attach it to the recycler
    if(adapter == null) {
        // mTiles is a class global ArrayList that contains the objects to display in the adapter, (NOTE: mTiles is not null and contains data when returning to this fragment on the back stack)
        adapter = adapterFactory.getAdapter(getContext(), mTiles);
        rvActions.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

- User navigates forward and adds Fragment2;
- FragmentManager().getChildren() -> return [Fragment1, Fragment2]
- User navigates backwards
- Pop the Fragment Back Stack
- FragmentManager().getChildren() -> return [Fragment1]

At this point, Fragment 1 calls `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()` again as shown in the fragment lifecycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

At this point, Fragment 1 remembers its past components and there is no need to reinitialize anything. The same RecyclerView as before is returned which has the same LayoutManager and Adapter as when it was created the first time. However, none of the adapter data shows in the view. Calling `NotifyDataSetChanged()` or any of those other adapter methods does not update the view as well. I'm a bit confused here. Do I need to create a new adapter every time? Do I need to some how unset the underlying data list for the adapter and relink it? I can't quite grok why this would be happening if all the data is there, for some reason the data just doesn't display in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a fragment is added the back stack `OnDestroyView` is called, destroying the view for your fragment, in your logic, `rvActions` is actually null when the fragment returns from the back stack, so is recreated in `OnCreateView` but `layoutManager` and `adapter` are not null. So when `rvActions` is recreated your logic does not allow for the layoutManager or adapter to be readded to the recyclerview. Simply changing to the following will fix your problem:

```
if (rvActions == null) {
// Grab a reference to the recycler widget
    rvActions = view.findViewById(R.id.feed_recycler);
    rvActions.setHasFixedSize(true);

// grab the appropriate layout manager from the injected factory then attach it to the recycler
    if (layoutManager == null) {
        layoutManager = feedFactory.getLayoutManager();
    }
    rvActions.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    // Grab the appropriate adapter from the injected factory then attach it to the recycler
    if(adapter == null) {
    // mTiles is a class global ArrayList that contains the objects to display in the adapter, (NOTE: mTiles is not null and contains data when returning to this fragment on the back stack)
        adapter = adapterFactory.getAdapter(getContext(), mTiles);  
    }
    rvActions.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I was leaning towards trying this. The issue right now is the factories for layoutmanager and adapter do not return a new instance every time so removing the if statements throws an error saying the layoutmanager is already in use with the old recyclerview (maybe I can null out the reference on destroy?). I'm going to make them return a new instance every time and then I'll post back if that fixes my problem. Thanks for the response!

Comment: that was exactly it! I shouldn't have declared the recycler view as a class global and instead get it inline during onViewCreated. I also made sure the factories returned new instances every time which was also part of the problem. Thanks for the help, cheers!